# How to print id of database on SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am trying to print the id of database that is integrated to my SharePoint site.It already prints the data related to that database.I want to store its id in a column in SharePoint list

Comment: You need an Id of the content database which stores SharePoint site data?

Comment: Are you looking for C# code or Powershell command?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you already tried this, is it not giving out the Id you're looking for?

```
SPSite siteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
SPContentDatabase contentDB = siteCollection.ContentDatabase;
Guid dbId = contentDB.Id;
```